# iOS development with FireMonkey on OS X Mountain Lion?

Tags: ios, delphi, delphi-xe2, firemonkey, osx-mountain-lion

Is it possible to use FireMonkey for iOS development on [OS X Mountain Lion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OS_X_Mountain_Lion)?

If yes, what are the installation / configuration steps?

Comment: I have been tested my fmx application on Mountain Lion and has no problem. No extra  installation / configuration steps is needed. everything is Ok.

Comment: AFAIK, the only problem is to get the iOS development tools installed on Mountain Lion as the setup instructions only work with the older XCode versions, which in turn do not work with Mountain Lion.

Comment: @UweRaabe many thanks! this was missing in my question

Comment: I agree. The XCode version is more relevant than the OS X version. I am using XCode 3.2.6 with XE 2 Update 4. Is anybody using any later XCode version?

Comment: I have XCode 4.4 installed and it seems fine, I'm only doing initial testing at the moment though.